Can not login in Gitlab registry with Gitlab runner ($CI_REGISTRY_USER/$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD causes 401)
I try to run a pipeline for building docker images via a Gitlab runner (docker executor). When the image is built, it should be pushed to the Gitlab registry to make it accessible for other jobs/stages. So in the before_script I try to execute docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY. Because of some reasons I don't know, this command causes an error and the runner log writes
Get "https://gitlab-registry-url/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

I checked the logs for the Gitlab registry and get this message
{"content_type":"application/json","correlation_id":"...","duration_ms":0,"host":"gitlab_registry_url","level":"info","method":"GET","msg":"access","proto":"HTTP/1.1","referrer":"","remote_addr":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy","remote_ip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx","status":401,"system":"http","time":"2024-04-27T13:51:44.372+02:00","ttfb_ms":0,"uri":"/v2/","user_agent":"Docker-Client/25.0.5 (linux)","written_bytes":87}

For debugging purposes, I tried to login from the Gitlab runner machine into the Gitlab registry (via terminal) and this works just fine.
The Gitlab instance (version 16.11.1) and the runner (version 16.9.0) are self hosted, both are on different VMs. The Gitlab instance and the registry are behind a reverse proxy (Nginx). The registry has it's own url.
The runner config.toml looks like
[[runners]]
  name = "Runner"
  url = "gitlab-instance-url"
  token = "xxxxxxxxx"
  token_obtained_at = xxxxxxx
  token_expires_at = xxxxxxx
  executor = "docker"
  clone_url = "gitlab-instance-url"
  [runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    Path = "path"
    Shared = true
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
    [runners.cache.s3]
      ServerAddress = "minio-instance-url"
      AccessKey = "xxxx"
      SecretKey = "xxxxx"
      BucketName = "gitlab-cache"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:stable"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/certs/client", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    network_mtu = 0

Has anybody experinced this behaviour too and found a solution or has a hint what causes this behaviour? Or does anybody know why the login with a Gitlab runner causes a HTTP 401 (Unauthorized) error?
Thanks in advance
